# Any SyncToy replacement?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SyncToy like application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97589/synctoy-like-application)

I use synctoy in Windows to keep my local files -> backup HDD in sync. Is there something like that in Ubuntu?