# SyncToy like application

Tags: software-recommendation, sync

Any Synctoy like software that supports scheduling and multiple folders selection? I need to synchronize One folder which consists of subfolders from multiple locations. Also changes should be 2 way, meaning file deleted from one location should be deleted in other and should not follow source and destination analogy of rsync.

Comment: I haven't yet found a solution that deals with moves/renames like SyncToy does.

Comment: git handles renames pretty well; there are some git-based sync applications ([git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) looks particularly interesting), though most require a bit of understanding of git.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pratik is not 100 % correct; Unison does have a nice GUI: 
[image: Unison GUI]

It can be helpful in getting you started.

However, it is also possible to run from the command line, which makes it easy to put in a [cron job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), so that you can schedule it to run every 15 minutes or whatever you want. You'll typically create a *profile* with a certain name, you can do this in the GUI, but then you can run that profile from the commandline like

```
unison -batch name_of_your_profile
```

This is useful since you can then make a cronjob out of it. Type `crontab -e`, then paste in the line

```
*/15 * * * *      /usr/bin/unison -batch name_of_your_profile   &> /tmp/unison-cron.log
```

and exit the editor. Your unison command will now run every 15 minutes, and output any errors to the file /tmp/unison-cron.log.

Actually, it seems like there's even a GUI for cron, [Gnome Schedule](http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/)([friendly intro to it here](http://maketecheasier.com/easy-way-to-schedule-and-automate-tasks-in-ubuntu/2008/06/16)). Never tried it, but I guess it makes running Unison from cron even more user-friendly …

See also the [Ubuntu wiki page on Unison](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unison).

Unison is quite powerful, I've used it for a long time to sync stuff between two laptops, a desktop and a remote server … It's quite good at ensuring you get the newest and correct content, and if there's a conflict it's easy to merge. It's not a backup tool, though; if you delete everything on one end, you'll find it deleted on the other end too ;-)

Comment: Did exactly whatever you told me to do and it worked. Thanks for understanding the question correctly and helping me out solving the tedious task of syncing the files. I really appreciate your help and I don't know how to thank you. :)

Comment: no problem, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

Lots of options... Many use rsync, as described here: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/backup

I like the graphical version Grsync as described here: http://www.linuxloop.com/2009/04/21/how-to-pain-free-backups-with-grsync-and-gnome-schedule/

Make sure to read the comments regarding scheduling...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried unison and cron together? unison does the two way syncing. cron does the scheduling. These are command line tools, not GUI applications.